# mysqli fetch отдает не тот тип значений таблицы

Tags: mysqli, php

Привет, Хешкод! Добрый вечер! Здравствуйте!

Есть таблица с полем типа `float`. Что я только не делал через MySQLi, чтобы он забрал из базы и положил мне в массив значение `float`, а не `string` как он это любит делать.

Я по быстрому набросал костылек, который перебивает строки во флоты. Но я очень надеюсь, что смогу его убрать и кто-нибудь мне скажет как же мне выбрать `float` из `MySQL`, чтобы мне не было стыдно.

Лол. Вот костылек:

```
$i = 0;
$d = count($regions_db);
while($i < $d)
{
    $regions_db[$i][1] = floatval($regions_db[$i][1]);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Костылек к вопросу приложите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня такое чувство, что сразу получить float из базы нельзя, хотя не уверен, надо основательно гуглить:

---

**БД:**

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (i INT, d1 DECIMAL(9,2), d2 DECIMAL(9,2));

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 101.40, 21.40), (1, -80.00, 0.00),
(2, 0.00, 0.00), (2, -13.20, 0.00), (2, 59.60, 46.40),
(2, 30.40, 30.40), (3, 37.00, 7.40), (3, -29.60, 0.00),
(4, 60.00, 15.40), (4, -10.60, 0.00), (4, -34.00, 0.00),
(5, 33.00, 0.00), (5, -25.80, 0.00), (5, 0.00, 7.20),
(6, 0.00, 0.00), (6, -51.40, 0.00);

SELECT i, SUM(d1) AS a, SUM(d2) AS bFROM t1 GROUP BY i HAVING a <> b;
```

---

**PHP**

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123456789");
mysql_select_db("test", $db) or die ('Нет такой схемы! : ' . mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT d1 FROM t1 WHERE i = 1 LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);

$a = $myrow["d1"];
echo $a;

echo "</br>";

$resourseType = gettype($myrow["d1"]);
print($resourseType);
```

---

**Возвращаемый тип:**

```
101.40
string
```